# Disable connection message PHP

Tags: php, logging, php-ini

I've been trying to disable the webserver logs printed to the host's console that come standard when running a PHP app, then logging my own messages in place of them, to no avail.

I haven't tried it yet, but I assume the solution lies somewhere within some sneaky php.ini settings?

Example:

```
#this
[date/time] ip -> /...

#in place of this
[date/time] ip:cid [status]: /...
 ...
```

### Solution:

I figured it out. Redirecting stderr input to `/dev/null` when starting the server then outputting to stdout gives the desired result.

Comment: Which log file is this found in?

Comment: @aynber, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. It's the host console's output. Will edit.

Comment: What is a "connection message?"

Comment: @PeeHaa `[Wed Feb 17 10:54:32 2016] 127.0.0.1:49861 [200]: /`, for example. Not sure what the technical name is

Comment: Are you asking about the webserver's logs? Where did you find that line?

Comment: @PeeHaa that's the name i was looking for. And as described, in the host console (running on my computer)

Comment: There is nothing printed to the "console" by default by php. Again: where / how did you find that line?